# How can I check the remaning limits in my marketing cloud instance?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Do we have any way to check the remaining limit of my org,as we have System Overview in sales/service cloud?

Limits may include:

1. Data Extension Storage limit
2. API limit
3. Super Messages Limit
4. Contacts Limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Updated Answer

A new report type has been added to the Report Catalog to enable you to review the Contact count on your Marketing Cloud account. Follow the steps below:

1. Select **Reports** from the Analytics Builder menu
2. Click Catalog at the top of the page
3. Select 'Contacts' from the Channel list in the left pane
4. Click **Create** next to 'Contact Counts'
5. Select a date range
6. View the report on page

### Previous Answer

> Review the answer above, just including this for historical purposes.

Surprisingly, the ability to check your utilization against your edition entitlement in Marketing Cloud does not exist at this time as I explained in [this previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133827/what-are-the-usage-charges-in-marketing-clouds-pricing-model/133828#133828).

You should in theory be able to calculate your Contacts by adding (and de-duplicating):

1. Contact Records in Contact Builder's All Contacts list
2. Subscribers in the All Subscribers list within the email app
3. Contacts that exists through a root relationship or population in Contact Builder
4. Any person who has been sent a message (email, SMS, Push, OTT)

...but that's not easy to do.

Currently, the only way to find out your current utilization is to contact your Account Manager, or open a support case.

Comment: SFMC has been infuriating with the customer service / support change (which even in premiere, is pretty wretched) and now followed by adding new limits and price points - which they won't even let you track!  I understand its how Salesforce works and yadda yadda yadda, but they should really wait till they are fully capable of providing support or sharing required limits before releasing the new protocols, etc.