# Differene between TriggeredSendID vs TriggeredSendCustomerKey?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Based on the documentation here https://medium.com/@charlie.fay/salesforce-marketing-cloud-ids-explained-e23fc6ac198d

Triggeredsendcustomerkey is the external key used for API calls and triggeredsendid is a unique identifier inside MC - can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Yes. Let me add that the customer key is set manually while the Id is generated by MC in the background when the TriggerdSend is created.

Answer (score 5):

The ID vs. Key definition is true across all objects inside of SFMC - Data Extensions, Send Definitions, SQL Queries, Triggered Send Definitions, etc.

The **ID** is a GUID that is created by SFMC when an object is created. It is read-only and will never be changed, until the object is deleted.  This is usually what is used internally or when using 3rd party API to integrate with SFMC. The reason is that this identifier will never change, so if someone goes into your account and accidently changes the name or key or location something, it will have no effect on the functionality of your call.

The **Key** is a user-defined string that can hold up to [36 characters](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314975&type=1&mode=1) (I believe you can edit some of them up to 200 characters, but honestly, 36 is best practice and recommended). This string is then read/write permission, allowing you to adjust it at any time you want, whether via the UI, API or Scripting language (AMPscript, SSJS). The purpose of the external key is for a friendly identifier for any querying or filtering you do via API or Scripting language. E.g. for Lookup functions, Core functions, etc.  As well as using Retrieve Requests inside API or filters, etc.  The risk with using these user-defined and editable identifiers is if it is changed, you will need to update all calls/functions that utilize the old identifier to correctly associate it with the new one, or the calls will break.

**ref:**
[SubscriberID vs. SubscriberKey](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/144574/difference-between-subscriber-id-and-subscriber-key-in-marketing-cloud)
[ContactKey vs. ContactID vs. SubscriberKey](https://marketingcloud.info/2019/12/03/what-is-the-difference-contact-key-vs-contact-id-vs-subscriber-key/)
[What is the difference between Primary Key Contact ID, Contact Key, Subscriber Key and Subscriber ID?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193008/what-is-the-difference-between-primary-key-contact-id-contact-key-subscriber-k?rq=1)