# Marketing Cloud, GDPR & Salesforce Individual Record

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce-id, gdpr

I'm planning a Salesforce & MC implementation and the client would like to include GDPR compliance.

We will be building a custom subscription centre (possibly using Formstack as I think I prefer it over Cloud Pages). Salesforce will be the Database of Record / Single Source of Truth. The Salesforce Record ID will be used as the MC Subscriber Key.

I am considering using the Salesforce Individual object, which has very little actual functionality currently. However it could be used as the store of Subscriber preferences. Using the Individual Record ID as the Subscriber Key in MC would also avoid the issue that Marketing Cloud Connect doesn't handle Lead Conversion - the Individual record doesn't change during this process.

That said, using the Individual object as the link to the Lead or Contact means you either need to have a formula field on the Individual object looking up to the Lead or Contact for the fields your require read access to for MC, or you have to span another layer when referencing something in MC (i.e. Individual>Lead/Contact>Field ). This is likely to cause some issues.

Interested to hear everyone's thoughts!

Cheers

Matt

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! On this forum you might get a (better) response if you rephrase your question with a specific issue in mind rather than asking for an open-ended discussion ("everyone's thoughts"). Example of a good question: [Avoiding creating duplicate Contacts in Marketing Cloud when using Sales Cloud records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169088). See [ask] for more details.

Comment: What's preventing you from using an app on Sales/Service Cloud like Privacy360? It comes with a cost and needs some configuration, but once in place, it works great.

Comment: Your idea of using the Individual Id as subscriber key is interesting in itself but will basically render Marketing Cloud Connect useless as this standard integration only works with the subscriber key based on Contact, Lead and User object records. Pretty much every functionality of the connector is based on this concept. This leads back to identigrals comment that the question is way to broad. My opinion: Answering your question is the typical scope of a paid consulting engagement by either Salesforce professional services or a partner.