# Does Marketing Cloud know to connect between Campaign Members and their associated Contacts or are these duplicates?

Tags: marketing-cloud, campaign-member

Please consider the two scenarios below:

**Scenario 1**

Using SQL, we're filtering Campaign Members based on some criteria to create a Sendable DE.

- Which is the correct relationship to use to SubscriberKey?
  The CampaignMemberId or the LeadOrContactId?
  If I don't use the LeadOrContactId, this would be considered as new contacts, right?
  Can anyone confirm/reject the above?

**Scenario 2**

- When we use the CampaignMember Object directly in Journey Builder - Does Marketing Cloud know to use the LeadOrContactId field, or are these counted as new contacts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely speaking, for a sendable Data Extension populated by SQL Query Activity, the sendable field in your data would be LeadOrContactId. Typically, though, you'd join in your SQL from CampaignMember_Salesforce to Lead_Salesforce to use the "_ContactKey" field from your Lead data. If your Lead has been converted to a Contact, you'd frequently want to use the Id of the new Contact, rather than that of the converted Lead.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(l._ContactKey,cm.LeadOrContactId) AS ContactKey,
    cm.CampaignId
FROM
    CampaignMember_Salesforce cm LEFT JOIN
    Lead_Salesforce l
        ON  cm.LeadOrContactId = l.Id
WHERE 
    cm.CampaignId = '70MYCAMPAIGNID'
```

For a Salesforce Campaign entry event in Journey Builder, you don't get to define the Contact Key. The Contact Builder/sendable relationships are selected for you. For regular Salesforce Data entry events, ensure you select "Lead ID/Contact ID" when prompted to select who you want to inject into the Journey Builder Interaction.

Comment: Thanks @Macca for the thorough answer.
Though I understend the solution you propose - what's the advantage to use l._ContactKey in this case? (Or any?)
At first sight it seems like an unnecessary JOIN that would always output the same value as cm.LeadOrContactId anyway.
What am I missing? Also, as far as I understood, when a Lead converts through a Lead Convert Activity in JourneyBuilder, Marketing Cloud keeps the same _ContactKey for the Contact, so it would make sense to join on Contact_Salesforce more than on Lead_Salesforce, no?

Comment: PS. When I say Marketing Cloud keeps the same _ContactKey, I refer to this answer:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169088/avoiding-creating-duplicate-contacts-in-marketing-cloud-when-using-sales-cloud-r

Comment: When a Lead is first created, SFMC uses the Lead Id for _ContactKey. When the lead is converted to a Contact, the _ContactKey changes to that of the Contact Id. If you send to  converted lead in Lead_Salesforce (or in a filtered DE based on that table),  you'll see you're actually sending to the Contact, not the Lead. This is usually the preferred behaviour... You want to see tracking information is Sales Cloud aligned with the Contact and not the now obsolete Lead record.

Comment: When you're looking to inject data using SQL Query Activities based on CampaignMembers, you'd probably want to do similar, but what you have in your CampaignMember_Salesforce table isn't the converted contact id, but potentially the old defunct Lead Id.

Comment: Oh, so the replies on the last StackEschange reference in the previous comment are misleading/out-dated. 

Is this true regardless if the Lead is converted in SFMC (Lead Convert Activity) or in SFDC (Manual convert by Sales Rep) ?

Comment: No. I don't see it as misleading. Related. Eliot was pointing out a rather unhelpful behaviour of Marketing Cloud where when your _ContactKey is updated in your Lead_Salesforce data to that of the Contact Id, behind the scenes your old Lead still sits there as an SFMC Contact and counts towards your contact count for billable purposes in SFMC. It effectively becomes orphaned from your Lead_Salesforce data, but you're still paying for the SFMC contact.

Comment: Thanks @Macca, and have you experienced any difference in behavior when converting from JB Activity (which updates the _ContactKey) vs. Manually Converting in the CRM ?
Does Manually converting in the CRM still creates duplicates in April 2020?