# All contacts limit

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have some questions here with the invoice we may get if we overcome the 45.000 contacts applicable in the Corporate licence.

The point is we are gonna import 40.000 contacts Manually (via import into Data Extension). And then, in the next month we will synchronize with Sales and some contacts will be duplicated in ALL CONTACTS because of different Contact Keys.

Is there any way to avoid this? Do the platform merge the contact in Sales with the one already in SFMC in order to avoid the duplication?

I have checked the link underneath, but still is not clear how this works

[What are the usage charges in Marketing Cloud's pricing model?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133827/what-are-the-usage-charges-in-marketing-clouds-pricing-model)

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Have you been using the subscriber id set to the salesforce record id or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing records to a regular Data Extension will not make them into billable Contacts, unless you target them with some outbound activity.

Smart solution is to use a proper `Contact Key` to begin with, unless you plan to later delete some Contacts.

Instead why not to export them out of Sales Cloud right now with already correct Contact Key's (**18** digit ID's) so when you later connect the Clouds, they will be properly recognized and not get duplicated.

If you exceed your Contact amount quota, they will just be billed as extra Contacts.