# Triggered Send – Transactional Mails

Tags: marketing-cloud

When sending transactional emails via Triggered Send and disabling the "Add subscribers to this list" option, all emails that will be sent doesn't count against the Marketing Cloud contact limit, is that assumption correct?

Answer (score 1):

In a webinar last thursday Darryl Brown stated that Triggered Sends can be configured that they won't create Contacts. He called that "Hidden Audience". If its available look up OfficeHours from 19th July 2018. I may look that up again aswell.

Comment: That would be great but it sounds highly unlikely as it sounds too much like a workaround for the financially relevant contact limit.

Answer (score 0):

from what I've been reading here: [What are the usage charges in Marketing Cloud's pricing model?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133827/what-are-the-usage-charges-in-marketing-clouds-pricing-model)

it doesn't seem correct. Hope this helps.